# $.ajax to ask php read file and return

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want use AJAX to ask PHP to read a file and return data. The problem is, PHP can read the file but AJAX cannot get the data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    timeout : 1000,
    url : '../tools/test2.php', //read file and echo
    dataType : 'json',
    cache : false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#demo2").val('loading..')
    },
    success : function(data) {
        $("#demo2").val('message:' + data) //this never can run
    }
});
```

```php
//test2.php 
<?php
    header("Content-type:text/html");

    $fileName = "./testFile.txt";
    $file = fopen($fileName, "r");
    echo fgets($file); 
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: You're not returning JSON, use `json_encode` to return a PHP object or array.

Comment: Whats the error you have? Did you try to Alert Data that return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

```
dataType : 'json',
```

And then you said:

```
header("Content-type:text/html");
```

So jQuery tried to parse your HTML as JSON, failed and ran the `error` handler (which does nothing because you didn't write one) instead of the `success` handler.

Fix your `dataType` (you can just remove it so that jQuery will respect the Content-Type header) or rewrite the PHP so it returns JSON instead of HTML.

(If you are actually returning plain text (since you have a `.txt` file) then say `Content-Type: text/plain`).